# Android custom record video get setAudioSource failed

Tags: android

i'm trying to have custom preview surface view for record video from own application, this code is my test but i get this error:

```
setAudioSource failed
```

My sample code:

```
    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.unlock();
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mRecorder.setVideoSize(176, 144);
        mRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(15);
        mRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mRecorder.setMaxDuration(7000); 
        mRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder.getSurface());
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mOutputFileName);

        mRecorder.prepare();
        Log.v(TAG, "MediaRecorder initialized");
        mInitBtn.setEnabled(false);
        mStartBtn.setEnabled(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on Android M, then you need to request permissions to record audio on first run. To accomplish this, ask the user if you can record audio when the application starts:

```
private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 29;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if (mContext.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    } else {
        Log.d("Home", "Already granted access");
        initializeView(v);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d("Home", "Permission Granted");
                initializeView(v);
            } else {
                Log.d("Home", "Permission Failed");
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "You must allow permission record audio to your mobile device.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        }
        // Add additional cases for other permissions you may have asked for
    }
}
```

Also, don't forget to add the following to your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```